# Cómo acceder carpetas de usuario en Windows para lanzar programas?

Tags: c#, windows

necesito saber como llamar a un programa en windows desde c# sin necesidad de saber el nombre de usuario de la carpeta donde se encuentra el programa. Es decir, ejecutar `C:/Users/sergio/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/Spotify.exe`, acceder a ese programa sin tener que poner el nombre de usuario `sergio` dentro de la ruta para que los puedan usar mas usuarios con otro username.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Desde C:/Archivos de Programa no has intentado?

Comment: si revisas el path que define el icono de la aplicacion que ruta visualizas? si usas la tecla de Windows + R se abre la ventana para iniciar aplicacion, si escribes solo Spotify, no lo ejecuta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes probar con este código para acceder al folder AppData sin saber el nombre de usuario:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias crack, ahora funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Con mucho gusto, que bueno que ya funcionó tu código :)

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la ruta base del usuario puedes usar la variable de entorno   "UserProfile" de la siguiente manera.

```
string appPath = @"AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Spotify.exe";
string basePath= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, appPath);
Console.WriteLine(fullPath);
//lanzar aplicacion 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fullPath);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: he copiado ese trozo de código, no me da ningún error de compilación, pero tampoco se abre spotify.

Comment: El fragmento de codigo solo obtiene la ruta en base del usuario, seria necesario abrir la aplicacion con una linea mas:   
           **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fullPath);**
ya edite la respuesta ejemplificando esto, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu archivo esta ubicado en `C:/Users/sergio/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/Spotify.exe` no encontraras en C# una forma de hacer referencia al mismo como no sea colocando la ruta completa y exactamente igual a como es, ten en cuenta que la ruta, es la ubicación dentro del sistema de archivo de tu dispositivo de almacenamiento, en este caso el disco duro de la PC, por tanto para acceder a el tienes que hacer referencia a toda la ruta sin suprimir ni cambiar nada si no el sistema no encontrará el archivo y lanzará una excepción.
Una solución podría ser colocar tu archivo en una carpeta de acceso global para todos los usuarios, por ejemplo `C:\Archivos de programa\WindowsApps\Spotify.exe`

Comment: SI claro, lo entiendo, pero no manera de hacerlo para que cualquier usuario(de windows) pueda ejecutar el programa y se le abra spotify? es decir si otro usuario ejecuta el progrma no le va a abri spotify debido a que la ruta especificada en el codigo hace referencia a mi usuario.